# Rename Image with PHP if image already exists

Tags: php, image

I'm working on a system that uses images, and the images are named by a md5-ed email. And I'd like to add a -1 -2 etc after the newly uploaded image if an image with the md5-ed email name already exists. Here's my code:

```
    public function upload() {  

    global $email;

    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
    $user     = $_SESSION['user'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    $new_file_name = md5($email);


    $fileExists = file_exists("../lib/uploads/" . $new_file_name);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM avatars WHERE ( name='$fileName' ) OR ( name='$new_file_name' ) ");

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);


    if ( $fileExists ) {

        $fileName = $new_file_name; 
        $first = 1;
        $separator = '-';

        while ( file_exists("../lib/uploads/" . $fileName) ) {

            preg_match('/(.+)'.$separator.'([0-9]+)$/', $fileName, $match);     

            $new_file_name = isset($match[2]) ? $match[1].$separator.($match[2] + 1) :$fileName.$separator.$first;

            $first++;   

        }

        $fileName = $new_file_name;

    } elseif ( empty( $fileName ) ) {

        echo '<div class="error">Please Select a file first.</div>';

    } else {

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"],
          "lib/avatars/" . $fileName);

        echo "<div class='success'>File $fileName Uploaded.</div>";  

    }

} // ends upload() function
```

But I don't know what's wrong, it uploads the image with it's original name. Not even with the md5-ed email as name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**

*You've messed up your if statements*.

**In detail**

This is very veryu very simple. In your last else (the one that executes when the file doesnt exist) you have

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"],
      "lib/avatars/" . $fileName);
```

But if you trace back, you will see that `$fileName` is set to

```
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
```

and not the md5 of the email. You have to remove the final `else` condition and have its code execute EVERY time. Of course as long as the `$fileName` is not empty.

**So your code should be:**

```
if ( $fileExists ) {

    $fileName = $new_file_name; 
    $first = 1;
    $separator = '-';

    while ( file_exists("../lib/uploads/" . $new_file_name ) ) {

        preg_match('/(.+)'.$separator.'([0-9]+)$/', $new_file_name, $match);    

        $new_file_name = isset($match[2]) ? $match[1].$separator.($match[2] + 1) :$new_file_name.$separator.$first;      
        $first++;   

    }
} 

// <----
// Moved this one outside, since it always executes
// ---->
$fileName = $new_file_name;

// <----
// Separated this if, since it has nothing to do with the above
// ---->
if ( empty( $fileName ) ) {

    echo '<div class="error">Please Select a file first.</div>';

} else {

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"],
      "lib/avatars/" . $fileName);

    echo "<div class='success'>File $fileName Uploaded.</div>";  

}

} // ends upload() function
```

**How you can optimize it**

This depends if you are expecting single users to have lot's of images. If this is NOT the case, then leave it as is.

Otherwise, you will quickly end up having to wait for a long time after uploading 10th, 20th photo.

One way to improve it would be to search for files in a directory that fit a pattern (in this case your md5). For example like this:

```
foreach (glob($md5 . "*") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

This way you instantly know if there are already files with this md5 and how many of them.

Comment: Now it uploads it with the md5, but if it already exists it doesn't adds a -1 at the end

Comment: Change your while function to use `$new_file_name` instead, since this is the variable you are updating: `while ( file_exists("../lib/uploads/" . $new_file_name) ) {`

Comment: And the same goes for all the $fileName's within your `while`. You are changing the `$new_file_name` variable, but you constantly refer to the original `$fileName`, which is still unchanged and contains the actual file name, not md5.

Comment: Updated my answer.Tested, works. You just need to refer to `$new_file_name` in your regexps.

Comment: Yup, that works. But for some reason it's not entering the file exists loop

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31824/discussion-between-zorleq-and-and0r1995)